# Is OracleDataSource.getConnection thread-safe?

Tags: java, oracle, thread-safety

I thought finding this answer would be easy...but not so much.

Does anyone know if the OracleDataSource.getConnection method is thread safe?

I do not mean the Connection objects it returns, but the calling of getConnection itself.

Specifically, this method: http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html#getConnection()

The docs and class doesn't say explicitly but, being as how its a connection pool, I'm inclined to believe it is.

Answer (score -1):

This is a problem discussed in *Java Concurrency in Practice (Brian Goetz)*:

**4.5.1. Interpreting Vague Documentation**

> Many Java technology specifications are silent, or at least unforthcoming, about thread safety guarantees and requirements for interfaces such as ServletContext, HttpSession, or DataSource.

...information about servlets...

> One can make a similar inference about the JDBCDataSource interface, which represents a pool of reusable database connections. A DataSource provides service to an application, and it doesn't make much sense in the context of a
>   single threaded application. It is hard to imagine a use case that doesn't involve calling getConnection from multiple threads. And, as with servlets, the examples in the JDBC specification do not suggest the need for any client side locking in the many code examples using DataSource. So, even though the specification doesn't promise that DataSource is thread-safe or require container vendors to provide a thread-safe implementation, by the same "it would be absurd if it
>   weren't" argument, we have no choice but to assume that DataSource.getConnection does not require additional client-side locking.
>   ...

Comment: Please fix this illegible mess.

Comment: @EJP, I added quote formatting. Is there anything else? It would be really helpful to understand what exactly can be considered to be a mess here.

Comment: @EJP I'm sorry to fail to fix it at the first try. Something was probably wrong in how my browser showed me the text. Let me know if the mess is still present in your browser. Now it looks good for me.