# JDBC issues with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I wanted to run new Connections and it's query executions on separate threads. I wanted to start the thread by initializing/connecting to the Connection and then wait for queries and run them in the same thread. My attempt was to start the thread and initialize the connection and then pause the thread and only resume when I call execute.

```
private static synchronized boolean isActive()
{
    return active;
}

private static synchronized void makeActive()
{
    active = true;
}

    public void run()
    {  
        try
        {
            if(conn == null) 
            {
                onConnect();
            }

            synchronized(this)
            {
               while(!isActive())
                {
                    System.out.println(isActive());
                    wait();
                }

                System.out.println("exec");
                onExecute();
            }
        }



        catch(InterruptedException | SQLException e)
        {
                System.out.println("exception " + e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

onConnect creates my `Connection` and `onExecute` is called to execute a query. I call a query outside the class which does this:

```
    public void execute(PreparedStatement statement, String query) throws SQLException
    {
        activeQuery               =   statement;
        makeActive();
}
```

Currently when I start the thread my onConnect() is getting skipped if I don't use `join()` and when I do get the onConnect to execute then the block after the `while(!isActive())` doesn't execute so i assume that it is always waiting..

Is there a better approach to using multiple threads in JDBC in this context or are there any obvious mistakes in this code?

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't understand it clearly, but are you trying to use 1 Connection object from multiple threads? It is usual to confine a single Connection object to just one thread. Also consider using a connection pool. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345436/is-oracledatasource-getconnection-thread-safe/31904374#31904374 and it is also said in the "Java Concurrency in Practice" book that Connection is not guaranteed to be thread-safe and requires client-side synchronization, but in most applications a Connection is just confined to 1 thread.

Comment: I am using a single connection per thread, one of the issues I was having was that I was initializing the connection in the run(), if I initialized it before starting the thread and then started the thread then it worked fine and no I wasn't using a connection pool but I'll definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like classic wait/notify pair:

```
public void execute(PreparedStatement statement, String query) throws SQLException
{
    synchronized(this){
        activeQuery = statement;
        this.notify();
    }
}
```

and inside run method:

```
  while( some_finish_cond ) {
      synchronized(this){
         while(activeQuery==null){
             this.wait();
         }
         System.out.println("exec");
         onExecute();
         activeQuery = null;
      }                  
  }
```

Comment: Is there anything I can do about the initialization of the Connection in the first if()? It seems that the thread is finishing before the Connection can be created and so consequently I'm getting null pointers because of it.

Comment: Can you give `onConnect`  source?

Comment: It just initializes the connection:                 
conn    =   DriverManager.getConnection(connection_url);

Comment: Everything looks fine, can you provide stack trace and code?

Comment: I think I'm just going to init the Connection before I start the thread.